# How can you tell windows to prefer a swap file on one driver over another?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a machine with both a SSD and a HDD in it.  I have two Windows installs one on the HDD and one on the SSD.

I've partitioned the SSD to have one OS in the majority of it and a small partition for swap on  in the remainder. The HDD has a different install of Windows.

For the Windows that is installed HDD
I setup the swap to have swap files on both drives (HDD and small SSD partition).  When I look at prefermance monitor stats, it looks like the HDD swap is used before the SSD swap.

How can I tell Windows to use the secondary SDD swap file before the HDD one?

Comment: Why did you create a second partition on the SSD just for the swap-file? Why did you put purposely a swap file on that volume?

Comment: You cannot do this. Windows will prioritise the OS drive because that's where it's installed. While I won't go into why it's a bad idea to have a paging file on an SSD, to achieve this, you'll have to remove the page file from the OS drive.

Comment: @Synetech I have more than enough memory, but I want any windows directed swapping out of parts of the OS to happen to my fast SSD not my slow HDD.

Comment: @RandolphWest With an install that is mainly used just for gaming and a decent amount of RAM, the repetitive rewrite shouldn't be much cause for concern.  With a write endurance of > 500,000 for any decent drive, 1 - 1.5 years of use as a swap drive shouldn't cause any issues in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System** click **Advanced System Setting** on the left. Under **Performance** click **Settings...** then click the **Advanced** tab. Click **Change** then uncheck **Automatically manage paging file size for all drives**. Then you can set the size to what ever you want, or click **No paging file**. After you're done with a drive click **Set** and you should be good to go.

Comment: That does not set priority, it turns the swap file off on that drive altogether.

Comment: @Synetech Right.  Since I'm using it in VMWare and in bare metal booting, I need the swap mainly when I'm using the VM where I limit the memory available.